# How may I find the vertical distance between points and segments?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have two sets of points. One of them is the main path of a moving thing. It consists of some segments, joined from the left point to the next one. The next set is also another moving thing. I want to find the vertical distance between each point of the second set of points from the segments of the first set vertically intercept it. They may intercept the segments in more than one point, so the vertical distances should be summed.

I used the following code. I think it works fine, unless one of the points in the second set of points aligned a point in the first set of points. How may I deal with that to get the real distance.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>()
        {
          new Point(1,1),
          new Point(4,2),
          new Point(6,1),
          new Point(4,1)
        };

        List<LineSegment> segments = new List<LineSegment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Point start = points[i];
            Point end = points[i + 1];
            segments.Add(new LineSegment(start, end));
        }

        points.Sort((p1, p2) =>
        {
            if (p1.X == p2.X)
            {
                return p1.Y.CompareTo(p2.Y);
            }
            return p1.X.CompareTo(p2.X);
        });


        List<Point> points2 = new List<Point>()
        {
          new Point(1.5,0),
          new Point(5,0)
        };


        points2.Sort((p1, p2) =>
        {
            if (p1.X == p2.X)
            {
                return p1.Y.CompareTo(p2.Y);
            }
            return p1.X.CompareTo(p2.X);
        });

        foreach (var point in points2)
        {
            if(point.X >= points.First().X && point.X <= points.Last().X)
            {
                List<LineSegment> segmentsIntercepts = new List<LineSegment>();
                foreach (LineSegment segment in segments)
                {
                    if (point.X >= Math.Min(segment.Start.X , segment.End.X)  && point.X <= Math.Max(segment.Start.X, segment.End.X))
                    {
                        segmentsIntercepts.Add(segment);
                    }  
                }
                double verticalDistance = 0;
                foreach (LineSegment seg in segmentsIntercepts)
                {
                    double slope = (seg.End.Y - seg.Start.Y) / (seg.End.X - seg.Start.X);
                    double yIntercept = seg.Start.Y - slope * seg.Start.X;
                    double predictedY = slope * point.X + yIntercept;
                    verticalDistance += Math.Abs(point.Y - predictedY);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(verticalDistance);

            }
        }
    }
}

public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public class LineSegment
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }

    public LineSegment(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
}
```

If I change the points to the following list, it does not work as I desired:

```
List<Point> points2 = new List<Point>()
{
    new Point(1.5,0),
    new Point(4,0)
};
```